# Set delay between starting nodes within launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, timeout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to put my nodes inside a launch file. The first node need to be up and running before the second node. Is it possible to set some timeout before the second starts. Like `usleep(time)` in roscpp

```
<launch>
<node name="talker" pkg="roscpp_tutorials" type="talker" />
//delay of e.g. 1second
<node name="listener" pkg="roscpp_tutorials" type="listener" />
</launch>
```

Is this technically possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233353/set-delay-between-starting-nodes-within-launch-file/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-05-01

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-05-01**:
Ros has no such feature. Why do you need this function? What do you really want to achieve? Having hardcoded dependencies like this is a bad sign. What happens to your second node if the first one has to be restarted?

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-05-01**:
Thank you, but I do not face dependencies, this was about is it theoretically possible. E.g. holding a presentation and not wanting to go to the pc. I say some stuff about the window popping up of the first node, then after 30s I can gently move over the the second. But this is ok.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-01-09**:
A potential proper solution is for one node to wait until another node is ready before properly starting up, similar to how `rosservice call --wait` works.  You can probably also use a [service to indicate whether a node has started up](https://answers.ros.org/question/164531/when-waiting-for-a-node-inside-another-node-should-i-use-a-service/).  In fact, it'd probably be nice if nodes by default took a "wait" arg that allows setting dependencies between nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a one-line solution that does not require any additional packages (it was a bit tricky):

You can make use of launch-prefix feature like so:

```
<arg name="node_start_delay" default="1.0" />  
<node name="listener" pkg="roscpp_tutorials" type="listener" launch-prefix="bash -c 'sleep $(arg node_start_delay); $0 $@' " />
```

the problem with using just launch-prefix="sleep 1.0; " was that the node launching command was passed as arguments to 'sleep'

---

Originally posted by [kushlik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40140/kushlik/) with karma: 396 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 38

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rosbq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40459/rosbq/) on 2019-05-29**:
Thank you! That worked for me!

**Comment by [akim](https://answers.ros.org/users/55027/akim/) on 2020-06-27**:
This saved my day!
I was doing delays with `timed_roslaunch` before, but creating a launch file for every node was a bit painful.
Thank you!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2021-01-26**:
cool idea! thanks

**Comment by [sean](https://answers.ros.org/users/36565/sean/) on 2021-09-09**:
Great answer! What’s the meaning for `$0 $@`?

**Comment by [kushlik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40140/kushlik/) on 2021-09-10**:
$0 is the name of the node that roslaunch will call and $@ are the arguments to that node / process. The they was to separate the process executable (node) and its arguments, otherwise the sleep function would not work. $0 and $@ are both bash syntax, you can check documentation for additional info.

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2022-03-08**:
Is there a way to delay launching the part in ""?

**Comment by [ThreeForElvenKings](https://answers.ros.org/users/54382/threeforelvenkings/) on 2023-05-02**:
Hi @zkytony did you figure this out?

Comment: More correct would be `launch-prefix="/bin/bash -c 'sleep 1; $0 &quot;$@&quot;'"` . Otherwise, more complex arguments are not passed correctly to the command.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is no such implementation. However, this was a topic brought up at the last ROS Live meeting, and seems that the idea is to try and allow a user to have more 'coding' freedom from within a launch file. I have seen some workarounds that people have posted in the past, and what they did was created a regular bash script that called roslaunch files from within itself, as it was easier (or maybe currently the only way) to implement a delay between roslaunch starts.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-06**:
To slightly clarify @l0g1x's answer, he means delaying by adding commands of the form `sleep 5` (delay of 5 sec) between the desired `roslaunch` / `rosrun` commands in the bash script. (Right?)

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2016-05-06**:
Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can perform a workaround by putting the delayed node into an extra launch file and run it via `timed_roslaunch`.
Explanation goes [here](http://wiki.ros.org/timed_roslaunch).
Script is available [here](https://github.com/warehouse-picking-automation-challenges/plocka_packa/blob/master/apc_simulator/scripts/timed_roslaunch.sh).

In your case:

```
<launch>
<node name="talker" pkg="roscpp_tutorials" type="talker" />
<node pkg="timed_roslaunch" type="timed_roslaunch.sh" args="1 roscpp_tutorials my_listener.launch" name="timed_roslaunch" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

Content of `my_listener.launch`

```
<launch>
<node name="listener" pkg="roscpp_tutorials" type="listener" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) with karma: 220 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jstm](https://answers.ros.org/users/35977/jstm/) on 2018-12-11**:
just what is was looking for